How to make surface mesh on boundary surface with TetGen from point cloud?
I have .node file which contains points of particles intersecting surfaces of my predefined geometry (these points are representing my point cloud). I am trying to make tetra mesh in this space using TetGen, but I also want surface mesh on boundary.
In my .node file I specified the points that are on the boundary with boundary marker 1. Tetgen returnes this:
lower plate boundary - meshed properly
outer cylindrical boundary - not meshed as I want.
I want the surface mesh on cylindrical boundary to be as one on the lower plate boundary. Any idea how to properly make this surface mesh?

Retopologize your geometry - e.g. https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

How am I suposed to do that? I just have a lot of random points and the ids of surfaces that these points are crossing.
